# three.js - How to set custom color to *.obj model when it is delivered without *.mtl file?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, .obj, mtl-file

I have a set of models in *.obj format that come without material files (*.mtl files). Some online services display these models correctly: https://3dviewer.net/, https://sketchfab.com/. But - according to the three.js documentation - in my project I only get an incorrect display of the model:
[image: my local result]

instead of:
[image: Online 3D Viewer (https://3dviewer.net/) result, that uses three.js too]

The developer https://3dviewer.net/ said that the idea on this service is that if the *.mtl file is not found, then the script sets the default color / material - paints the entire product in one color.

How to color an object from a *.obj file to a selected color using three.js tools?

For testing, I attach a model file that comes without a material file: [test sample *.obj file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ygvu-2yYZXHEU01HeBtS7LClNVqrlpGf/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the OBJ is not exported correctly. When using macOS preview, BabylonJS or the `OBJLoader` of three.js, the faces seem to have the wrong winding order. You should get the desired result by doing the following in your `onLoad()` callback:

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.BackSide } );

obj.traverse( function( child ) {

    if ( child.isMesh ) child.material = material;

} );
```

Comment: Yes, this is what caused the problem to be fixed. The model now looks natural.